# Make a People Chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I want to create a visual count of people using a person icon to represent a number of people - like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this in SSRS? I was also hoping to have a quarter/half/three-quarters of a person when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is possible to do this through SSRS on it's own no.  There isn't support (as far as I'm aware) for duplicating images in this way based on a value.

An alternative (assuming you have access to the background query) would be to use something like Wingdings (yes it does have a use!)

My thought would be if you could get the query to return a string with the number of characters that you wish to display, you could then format this in SSRS to show a number of images related to this.

For example

```
--Assuming noOfDeaths is a field in table myTable

DECLARE @LoopCount INT
DECLARE @LoopTotal INT
DECLARE @NoOfDeathsIcon VARCHAR(1000)

SET @LoopCount = 0
SET @LoopTotal = (SELECT MAX(noOfDeaths) FROM myTable)
SET @NoOfDeathsIcon = ''

WHILE (@LoopCount < @LoopTotal) 
BEGIN
    SET @NoOfDeathsIcon = @NoOfDeathsIcon + 'N' -- 'N' is equal to the poison sign in Wingdings
    SELECT @LoopCount = @LoopCount + 1
END

INSERT INTO myTable(noOfDeathIcon)
VALUES (@NoOfDeathsIcon)

--Inserts 'NNNNNNNN' into the field noOfDeathIcon
```

You could then configure the SSRS report to take this field and format it as Wingdings to get the following result

[image]

Note this solution only works for a single line, but I'm sure a Common table Expression could be used to iterate over a number of lines to generate the strings.

For reference, the Windings character sets are displayed [here](http://speakingppt.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/webdings-wingdings-character-map-speakingppt.png)

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of a somewhat similar solution using the SSRS **Space** function and **Replac**ing the spaces with a character. But neither would work with my need for part of a person. I'm thinking of trying to do it with a graphic in THE MATRIX.